# libavcodec/opt.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android

I trying to compile a project using FFMpeg but it's giving this error of libavcodec/opt.h missing.    I take a look at the source directory and I don't think there's a file called opt.h.    The error seems a bit strange.

the Project of FFMpeg for Android. The opt.h put into the libavutil folder. Yet when I try build it, it complains of missing opt.h in libavcodec –

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search, I see lots of references to libavcodec/opt.h, so it appears to be a real file that you are missing. I haven't done any projects in Android with FFMpeg, so I don't know off-hand, but it does appear to be a file that others are using.

Answer (score 0):

On the Github mirror of the ffmpeg - project the 0.6 - release branch contains a libavcodec/opt.h header

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release/0.6/libavcodec/opt.h

Comment: But not for the Project of FFMpeg for Android. The opt.h put into the libavutil folder.  Yet when I try build it, it complains of missing opt.h in libavcodec